# How to fix mongo index creation after update to Spring Boot 2.2?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

On the previous version of Spring Boot (2.1.9) everything worked fine. I'd updated it to `2.2.2.RELEASE` (with dependency management plugin used), and have started to get an error:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:
Cannot create index for '' in collection 'testDTO' with keys 'Document{{_id=1, version=1}}' and
options 'Document{{name=optimistic_concurrency_idx}}'.;
nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException:
Command failed with error 67 (CannotCreateIndex): 'Unknown index plugin '1'' on server mongo:27017.
The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Unknown index plugin '1'", "code" : 67, "codeName" : "CannotCreateIndex" }
```

I'd searched, but didn't find any way to fix it.
Along with that, I have messages in logs:

```
Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class java.time.Instant as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
Registering converter from class java.time.Instant to class java.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
```

But as I've read [here](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAMONGO/issues/DATAMONGO-2400?filter=allopenissues), it's not so important.
Also, this logs message doesn't look important as well:

```
Automatic index creation will be disabled by default as of Spring Data MongoDB 3.x.\n\tPlease use 'MongoMappingContext#setAutoIndexCreation(boolean)' or override 'MongoConfigurationSupport#autoIndexCreation()' to be explicit.\n\tHowever, we recommend setting up indices manually in an application ready block. You may use index derivation there as well.\n\n\t> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\t> @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)\n\t> public void initIndicesAfterStartup() {\n\t>\n\t>     IndexOperations indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(DomainType.class);\n\t>\n\t>     IndexResolver resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(mongoMappingContext);\n\t>     resolver.resolveIndexFor(DomainType.class).forEach(indexOps::ensureIndex);\n\t> }\n\t> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n","component":"org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator
```

Because I' ve added `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation: true` to my `application.yml`, but the message is still present because it doesn't have any flag checking.

I've tried to downgrade the `spring-data-mongo` (and `boot-starter` as well), but it can't configure the context with `ClassNotFound` exceptions.

Was anybody faced with this problem? **How to solve it?**

Comment: How did things pan out with this problem, could you solve it? I just ran into this and am wondering whether it may disappear upgrading to 2.3 and beyond – the thread on https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28478 does not provide a satisfying answer either.